# Cursor not working in Android sqlite

Tags: android, sql, cursor, android-sqlite

My android app has 2 tables `Projects` and `Tasks`.

Each `Project` can have multiple `Tasks`.

Like below

[image]

Now I want to sum up all proportion values of the single `task` table

I did it.. but the issue is its adding proportion values from all task tables !

The cursor I coded is as follows

```
    public int sumproportion(long projectId){

    int value = 0;
    int p = 0;  

    Cursor cu = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_TASKS, null);

    ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();
    if (cur != null) {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                temp.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("proportion"))); // "Title" is the field name(column) of the Table                 
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
    }       

    Object ia[] = temp.toArray();

    for(int i=0; i<ia.length; i++)
    {
    p = Integer.parseInt((String) ia[i]);   
    value = value + p;

    }
    System.out.println("Value is: " + value); 

    return value;       
}
```

When I added cursor as below

```
            Cursor cur = mDatabase.query(DBHelper.TABLE_TASKS, mAllColumns,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_TASK_PROJECT_ID + " ="+String.valueOf(projectId),
            null, null, null, null);
```

It doesn't add anything. Can any one help fix it please?

Comment: I don't see any WHERE clause in your SQL. Then of course you get all rows as result.

Comment: am not sure but as far as i know ! DBHelper.COLUMN_TASK_PROJECT_ID + " ="+String.valueOf(projectId)     is the WHERE Clause in second cursor i used....

Comment: So that results in a string and you could print that string. That would help in debugging the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can just use query like this `SELECT SUM(proportion) from TABLE_TASK`. `proportion` should have numeric type.

Secondly, verify that your Cursor return any rows. Probably you pass wrong `projectId` if there no rows.

Comment: i am using the same projectId  in other function and it works fine ! As far as proportions.are concerned , am able to sum it for all the tasks ! so it works ! problem is getting the selective proportions to add ,which is because of Selection query i guess